# Return a (functional) component if not null

Tags: javascript, react-native

I wish to return a functional component as the result of the outer (functional) component if it's not null (and otherwise skip over it to the normal return statement).

The following works:

```
if (MyComponent() != null) {
  return <MyComponent />
}
```

But is that the right way to do it?

The logic that dictates whether or not MyComponent is null is quite complex, and I want it to remain inside the component instead of having to build the if condition from it.

Comment: ```MyComponent() && <MyComponent />``` should work too

Comment: Thanks @KetanRamteke - is there a downside to doing that? E.g. does calling the function and then rendering the component execute the code it contains twice?

Comment: tbh, you might as well use simple ```<MyComponent />``` instead of using any conditional statement, if there is something to render in that component then it will show up those elements if it's null then nothing will be rendered.

Comment: Are you literally calling `MyComponent()` or is that meant to be `shouldRenderMyComponent()`?

Comment: I would suggest to add a `placeholder` prop to your `MyComponent` and simply let it do the defaulting. Then pass the value from your "normal return statement" in from the outer component.

Comment: @Bergi - yes, literally MyComponent() - as the logic that decides if the component should render is inside the component.

Comment: @Geat No, definitely don't do that. It will not be a component, just a functional call, and all its hooks and state will be part of the outer component. At best, use `const resultElement = MyComponent(); if (result) return resultElement; else return defaultElement;` - but then don't use `<MyCompoent />` as well.